# Drop application shortcut into qt application (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, uwp, windows-shell

I'm currently trying to get more information about the application which is dropped into my Qt-Application. Here are a few information about the scenario:

- The app is dragged from the start menu
- The app is an Windows UWP app from the store
- I want to be able to start the dropped app later on

I'm receiving the MIME data correctly and it has following formats:

```
"application/x-qt-windows-mime;value=\"Shell IDList Array\""
"text/uri-list"
"application/x-qt-windows-mime;value=\"FileContents\""
"application/x-qt-windows-mime;value=\"FileGroupDescriptorW\""
"application/x-qt-windows-mime;value=\"Preferred DropEffect\""
```

The `text/uri-list` is empty since it's and UWP app and the don't have a traditional path. From the `FileGroupDescriptorW` I can retrieve the application name but nothing of interest for me atm.

I retrieved and printed the `Shell IDList Array` information. It looks like this:
[image]

In order to start an UWP app I need their package-name (`VideoLAN.VLC_paz6r1rewnh0a`) and their application-id (`App`). It's concatenate in the end like this `VideoLAN.VLC_paz6r1rewnh0a!App`.

I can see the data, inside the `Shell IDList Array`, but I don't know how to retrieve them.

Over Shell commands I can get the the [IShellItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellitem) of the application and get the display name of it (for example). For this i reinterprated the data as [CIDA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/ns-shlobj_core-cida) and created an IShellItem out of it using [SHCreateShellItemArrayFromIDLists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-shcreateshellitemarrayfromidlists). Now I'm stuck there and the documentation is kinda... spare.

Does anybody has information/guidance for me, how to retrieve the data I want to?

Comment: I don't know Qt, but you should get an `IDataObject` in your Qt application? In this case, you can simply call `SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject`

Comment: @SimonMourier I can do something like this:  `LPCITEMIDLIST item = GetPIDLItem(idList, 0);  LPCITEMIDLIST folder = GetPIDLFolder(idList);  IDataObject * pDataObj = NULL;  SHCreateDataObject(folder, 1, &item, NULL, IID_IDataObject, (void**)&pDataObj);`

I can get to the ShellItem itself already, but I can't access request the data I need. I don't really know, how to use the IShellItem to get to my data

Comment: I know what's a PIDL and how you can with it, but how come you don't have access to an already built IDataObject? That's how Windows d&d works. Otherwise, what you can do is create an IDataObject from scratch using SHCreateDataObject(null, 0, null, null, IID_IDataObject, &da) and then do da->SetData() with CIDA format, pass the data you have, and then SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject from this new data object.